# How to Get data from Bluetooth barcode scanner to reactJS application in chrome

Tags: reactjs, bluetooth, barcode-scanner, webapi

I am working on a inventory management project where we need to scan barcodes using Bluetooth barcode scanners and handle those data with reactJS application in chrome browser.
I tried using bluetooth web api and connected to a device but don't know how to get data from it... **(Or I am totally wrong to use bluetooth web api and the bluetooth scanner behaves just like the USB scanner , i.e. as a keyboard, once it's paired and connected to the computer directly)**

```
/*Tried out till this in onClick of a button*/
navigator.bluetooth
        .requestDevice({ acceptAllDevices: true })
        .then((device) => {
          console.log(device.gatt);
          return device.gatt.connect();
        })
        .then((server) => {
          console.log(server);
          return server;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
```

Comment: Please add some code to support your question.

Comment: @kiner_shah I am not sure if using bluetooth api to connect to a barcode scanner and get data is the right approach... I've read that the USB scanner behaves just like a keyboard (i.e. we can caputure keypress events and get data) - but idk if that applies to the bluetooth scanners too once it's paired and connected

Comment: Which browser are you using? Note that Web Bluetooth API has partial support for some features based on browsers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Bluetooth_API. Also, this API is non-standard I guess.

Comment: @kiner_shah I am using Chrome Version 96.0.4664.110 (Official Build) (64-bit). It is supported in the browser am using (i've enabled the necessary flags). Is there any way to achieve this thing am trying to do (since bluetooth api is an experimetal feature)?